# What does $\bigoplus$ mean when applied to two sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

What does $\bigoplus$ mean when applied to two sets?

For example if $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$, then what is $A\bigoplus B$?

Comment: Depends on the context, it's usually the direct sum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum

Comment: You need to provide more context. $\oplus$ is commonly used for the exclusive or operation on propositions, but that corresponds to the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) operation on sets which is usually written as $\ominus$ or $\Delta$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Other notations for symmetric difference that I have seen include $\oplus$ and even simply $+$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: fair enough, but the OP still needs to supply more context to get a good answer.

Comment: @RobArthan: Oh, absolutely! Especially after combining the abstract algebra tag with an example that doesn’t seem to fit it at all well.

Comment: For sets, you might sometimes see $\oplus$ for "disjoint union".